# Terminal closes itself when running many python processes

Tags: shell, fedora, python, crash, parallelism

I was trying to run multiple machine learning experiments simultaneously to save time. My OS is Fedora 36, and I use emacs. To automate the experiment I used `runs.py`

```
import subprocess

subprocess.run("python train.py python train.py python train.py python train.py", shell=True)
```

where `train.py` trains the neural network and I am just using different seeds.

Then, I open multiple shells inside emacs where in each I run `python runs.py`. I can do at most 5 shells, when I open a sixth one and run `python runs.py`, then emacs and the terminal close with no error. I am sure there is a log somewhere, but I don't know where. Why could this happen? `train.py` uses the GPU, but there is enough memory, there is also enough RAM to run more, so I have no idea what's causing this.

I'd appreciate any help. I know the information I provided might not be enough, but I am not sure what else to say that could be potentially relevant.

Comment: Try opening `emacs` from the command line (your terminal) and run the programs. All logs (`stdout` and `stderr`) should be printed in the terminal. Thus when `emacs` crashes you may see what error is causing a crash.

Comment: I open it from the command line: 'emacs -nw'. But I can't see any logs because when it crashes, it closes the terminal automatically.

Comment: Oh I see, it crashes all process. Maybe redirecting output to a file might work: `emacs -nw &>/home/user/somefile` or `stderr` only: `emacs -nw 2>/home/user/errfile`

Comment: I did that and the errfile has nothing on it.

Comment: I'm thinking your process may be killed by another one. Do you have oom killer? Try running: `systemctl status systemd-oomd`

Comment: So, after all, it seems it might be a memory problem. I get `Killed due to memory used`. Thanks for your help! Now I know what needs to be fixed. My program saves intermediate results as it runs, so at some point I run out of memory. It wasn't obvious to me because at first there is enough memory, but it gets occupied quickly.